# Deploying React with Github actions

Tags: github-actions, devsecops

Need advice with DevSecOps best practices for building CI/CD pipeline using Github actions and terraform to deploy on ACR on Azure

try to search and found only high level practices.

if there is an example repo will be appriciated

Comment: [Example workflow](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/.github%2Fworkflows%2Fpublish-master.yml#L312-L320)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.